# Extract information for date from other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I working with monthly data. Data is in a specific format in two columns `Month` and `Year`. Below you can see a sample of data:

```
df<-data.frame(
              Month=c("m1","m2","m3","m4","m5","m6","m7","m8","m9","m10","m11","m12"),
       Year=c("2020","2020","2020","2020","2020","2020","2020","2020","2020","2020","2020","2020"))
```

Now I want to convert this data, from that format into the format shown below or more precisely in column `Date`

[image]

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base` R you can do:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(paste0(df$Year, gsub("m", "-", df$Month, fixed = TRUE), "-01"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `parse_number` and `my` function -

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(Month = parse_number(Month), 
         Date = my(paste(Month, Year)))

#   Month Year       Date
#1      1 2020 2020-01-01
#2      2 2020 2020-02-01
#3      3 2020 2020-03-01
#4      4 2020 2020-04-01
#5      5 2020 2020-05-01
#6      6 2020 2020-06-01
#7      7 2020 2020-07-01
#8      8 2020 2020-08-01
#9      9 2020 2020-09-01
#10    10 2020 2020-10-01
#11    11 2020 2020-11-01
#12    12 2020 2020-12-01
```

Base R option -

```
transform(df, Date = as.Date(paste(1, sub('m', '', Month), Year), '%d %m %Y'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
as.Date(paste0(df$Year, '-', gsub('\\D+', '', df$Month), '-01'))

#[1] "2020-01-01" "2020-02-01" "2020-03-01" "2020-04-01" "2020-05-01" "2020-06-01" "2020-07-01" "2020-08-01" "2020-09-01" "2020-10-01" "2020-11-01" "2020-12-01"
```